# Analytic function/logic to get min and max record date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

I have a requirement to fetch value based on eff_dt and end date. given below sample data.

Database : Oracle 11g

Example data:

| id | val | eff_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 100 | 01-Jan-21 | 04-Jan-21 |
| 10 | 105 | 05-Jan-21 | 07-Jan-21 |
| 10 | 100 | 08-Jan-21 | 10-Jan-21 |
| 10 | 100 | 11-Jan-21 | 17-Jan-21 |
| 10 | 100 | 18-Jan-21 | 21-Jan-21 |
| 10 | 110 | 22-Jan-21 | null |

output:

| id | val | eff_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 100 | 01-Jan-21 | 04-Jan-21 |
| 10 | 105 | 05-Jan-21 | 07-Jan-21 |
| 10 | 100 | **08-Jan-21** | **21-Jan-21** |
| 10 | 110 | 22-Jan-21 | null |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex SQL query - collapsing date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449521/complex-sql-query-collapsing-date-ranges)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and then aggregate:

```sql
SELECT id,
       val,
       MIN(eff_date) AS eff_date,
       MAX(end_date) AS end_date
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY eff_date)
           - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, val ORDER BY eff_date) AS grp
  FROM   table_name t
)
GROUP BY id, val, grp
ORDER BY id, eff_date;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, val, eff_date, end_date) AS
SELECT 10, 100, DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-04' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 105, DATE '2021-01-05', DATE '2021-01-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 100, DATE '2021-01-08', DATE '2021-01-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 100, DATE '2021-01-11', DATE '2021-01-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 100, DATE '2021-01-18', DATE '2021-01-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 110, DATE '2021-01-22', null FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | VAL | EFF_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 100 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 |
| 10 | 105 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 |
| 10 | 100 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 2021-01-21 00:00:00 |
| 10 | 110 | 2021-01-22 00:00:00 | *null* |

---

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER BY eff_date
  MEASURES
    FIRST(val) AS val,
    FIRST(eff_date) AS eff_date,
    LAST(end_date) AS end_date
  PATTERN (same_val+)
  DEFINE same_val AS FIRST(val) = val
)
```

Which has the same output and is likely to be more efficient.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/td4x3fZ-)

Comment: @Vicki Ask another question and then you might find someone who can answer that question (I cannot). Or else you can search the internet and you'll probably find the answer.