# SQL Server : merge 2 rows into 1 with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that returns this results

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|ID |ID1|ID2|IDP|IDC|IDA|START_DATE         |END_DATE           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|10 |2  |1  |10 |152|15 |1900-01-01 08:10:00|1900-01-01 09:10:00|
|10 |2  |1  |20 |152|12 |1900-01-01 09:10:00|1900-01-01 10:10:00|
|10 |2  |1  |30 |152|11 |1900-01-01 10:10:00|1900-01-01 11:10:00|
|10 |2  |1  |10 |152|15 |1900-01-01 11:10:00|1900-01-01 12:10:00|
|10 |2  |1  |10 |152|15 |1900-01-01 12:10:00|1900-01-01 13:10:00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to merge the last 2 rows because the END_DATE of the fourth row is equal to the START_DATE of fifth row. The other rows are all right and they have to be like that. So I would like to have this result.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|ID |ID1|ID2|IDP|IDC|IDA|START_DATE         |END_DATE           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|10 |2  |1  |10 |152|15 |1900-01-01 08:10:00|1900-01-01 09:10:00|
|10 |2  |1  |20 |152|12 |1900-01-01 09:10:00|1900-01-01 10:10:00|
|10 |2  |1  |30 |152|11 |1900-01-01 10:10:00|1900-01-01 11:10:00|
|10 |2  |1  |10 |152|15 |1900-01-01 11:10:00|1900-01-01 13:10:00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

With the fourth and fifth rows

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|10 |2  |1  |10 |152|15 |1900-01-01 11:10:00|1900-01-01 12:10:00|
|10 |2  |1  |10 |152|15 |1900-01-01 12:10:00|1900-01-01 13:10:00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

They have to became only one

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|10 |2  |1  |10 |152|15 |1900-01-01 11:10:00|1900-01-01 13:10:00|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please add your trial query

Comment: See also answers for similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068619/merging-date-intervals-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+ it can be done much more efficiently with `LAG` function.

In SQL Server 2008 I'd use cursor if the amount of data is significant.

The following set-based approach works, but it is likely to be slow with large table.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
    (ID int, ID1 int, ID2 int, IDP int, IDC int, IDA int, 
    START_DATE datetime2(0), END_DATE datetime2(0));

INSERT INTO @T
    (ID, ID1, ID2, IDP, IDC, IDA, START_DATE, END_DATE)
VALUES
    (10, 2, 1, 10, 152, 15, '1900-01-01 08:10:00', '1900-01-01 09:10:00'),
    (10, 2, 1, 20, 152, 12, '1900-01-01 09:10:00', '1900-01-01 10:10:00'),
    (10, 2, 1, 30, 152, 11, '1900-01-01 10:10:00', '1900-01-01 11:10:00'),
    (10, 2, 1, 10, 152, 15, '1900-01-01 11:10:00', '1900-01-01 12:10:00'),
    (10, 2, 1, 10, 152, 15, '1900-01-01 12:10:00', '1900-01-01 13:10:00');
```

**Query**

`CTE_Merged` joins the table with itself on all `ID` columns and start+end dates. It will produce one row for each pair of rows that should be merged.

`CTE_Join` joins original table with `CTE_Merged` twice. First - to get the `FinalEndDate` for the rows that should be preserved; second - to filter out second row of the merged pair (using `WHERE CTE_Join.M2END_DATE IS NULL`).

Run this query step by step and examine intermediate results to understand how it works.

```
WITH
CTE_Merged
AS
(
    SELECT
        T1.ID
        ,T1.ID1
        ,T1.ID2
        ,T1.IDP
        ,T1.IDC
        ,T1.IDA
        ,T1.START_DATE
        ,T2.END_DATE AS MergedEndDate
    FROM
        @T AS T1
        INNER JOIN @T AS T2
            ON  T1.ID  = T2.ID
            AND T1.ID1 = T2.ID1
            AND T1.ID2 = T2.ID2
            AND T1.IDP = T2.IDP
            AND T1.IDC = T2.IDC
            AND T1.IDA = T2.IDA
            AND T1.END_DATE = T2.START_DATE
)
,CTE_Join
AS
(
    SELECT
        T.ID
        ,T.ID1
        ,T.ID2
        ,T.IDP
        ,T.IDC
        ,T.IDA
        ,T.START_DATE
        ,T.END_DATE
        ,M1.START_DATE AS M1START_DATE
        ,M1.MergedEndDate AS M1END_DATE
        ,ISNULL(M1.MergedEndDate, T.END_DATE) AS FinalEndDate
        ,M2.START_DATE AS M2START_DATE
        ,M2.MergedEndDate AS M2END_DATE
    FROM
        @T AS T
        LEFT JOIN CTE_Merged AS M1
            ON  T.ID  = M1.ID
            AND T.ID1 = M1.ID1
            AND T.ID2 = M1.ID2
            AND T.IDP = M1.IDP
            AND T.IDC = M1.IDC
            AND T.IDA = M1.IDA
            AND T.START_DATE = M1.START_DATE
        LEFT JOIN CTE_Merged AS M2
            ON  T.ID  = M2.ID
            AND T.ID1 = M2.ID1
            AND T.ID2 = M2.ID2
            AND T.IDP = M2.IDP
            AND T.IDC = M2.IDC
            AND T.IDA = M2.IDA
            AND T.END_DATE = M2.MergedEndDate
)
SELECT
    CTE_Join.ID
    ,CTE_Join.ID1
    ,CTE_Join.ID2
    ,CTE_Join.IDP
    ,CTE_Join.IDC
    ,CTE_Join.IDA
    ,CTE_Join.START_DATE
    ,CTE_Join.FinalEndDate
FROM CTE_Join
WHERE
    CTE_Join.M2END_DATE IS NULL
;
```

**Result**

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID | ID1 | ID2 | IDP | IDC | IDA |     START_DATE      |    FinalEndDate     |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| 10 |   2 |   1 |  10 | 152 |  15 | 1900-01-01 08:10:00 | 1900-01-01 09:10:00 |
| 10 |   2 |   1 |  20 | 152 |  12 | 1900-01-01 09:10:00 | 1900-01-01 10:10:00 |
| 10 |   2 |   1 |  30 | 152 |  11 | 1900-01-01 10:10:00 | 1900-01-01 11:10:00 |
| 10 |   2 |   1 |  10 | 152 |  15 | 1900-01-01 11:10:00 | 1900-01-01 13:10:00 |
+----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: That is PERFECT! Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that your output query is a table, than this might works:

(@tmp - table with your return result)

```
select   t.id,
         t.id1,
         t.id2,
         t.idp,          t.idc,
         t.ida,
         t.startDate,
         t2.enddate  from @tmp t left outer join @tmp t2 on t2.startDate = t.enddate where t2.id is not null
```

But as Joe Taras said, please add what you have written or the table where the data are stored.

Comment: That query merges my fourth row and fifth row but compromizes the START_DATE and END_DATE of the other records

Example of the first row
Before START DATE
1900-01-01 09:10:00
After
1900-01-01 10:10:00