# PostgreSQL: Dynamically build query for box datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I am trying to construct a statement that dynamically builds the syntax to properly query a box data type in postgres.

It looks something like the following:

```
Note: foo1 is an integer value

with a as (
  select foo1 from foo where id = 1), 
     b as (
  select a, b, c from bar where a && '''('||a.foo1||',0,'||a.foo1||',0)''')
select * from b;
```

The above query yields: `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type box: "'("`

Is it possible to build this type of query dynamically?

See the answer [Another similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000555/postgresql-matching-interval-between-start-and-end-time-against-timestamp) that shows how you would normally query the box data type.

Comment: Replace `'''('||a.foo1||',0,'||a.foo1||',0)''')` with `BOX(POINT(a.foo1,0),POINT(a.foo1,0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the whole query:

```
SELECT b.a, b.b, b.c
FROM   foo f
JOIN   bar b ON b.a && box(point(f.foo1,0), point(f.foo1,0))
WHERE  f.id = 1;
```